Getting Nvidia graphics to work on a Thinkpad T430 and Ubuntu 24.04
I have a Thinkpad T430 which has an intel iGPU and an Nvidia 5400M Fermi-based Discrete GPU. I am now running Kubuntu 24.04 on it, which runs the 6.8.0 kernel. I noticed that while installing, the available proprietary driver does not support my machine, because it is an old GPU, and the last supported driver for this GPU is nvidia-390. However, Ubuntu 24.04 does not provide nvidia-390. I attempted to use the latest driver in the past, but this caused all sort of problems.
I would like to connect an external 3440x1440 monitor to it via my dock. It does work (if I start up the laptop with the lid closed, or wake it up with the lid closed), but it is rather slow. Based on what I can tell, it seems to be using the intel iGPU to draw the pixels to the screen, and it feels like the iGPU simply couldn't give good performance. I can actually see the 2 triangles being rendered when any movement occurs on the screen.
When I used this laptop on Windows, I noticed that the Nvidia switcher would use the nvidia GPU whenever I connected an external monitor to this laptop via DisplayPort (and also the dock). This is probably why I did not face this sort of lag in Windows, but I am on Linux.
I tried to use Nouveau, which does provide decent support, but I could not figure out how to get nouveau and the nvidia GPU to drive the display by default. The system still uses the Intel GPU by default for driving the display. This is despite teh fact that I can use DRI_PRIME=1 to switch to noveau for specific applications. However, driving the display still happens with the iGPU.
My next solution is to try using the proprietary nvidia-390 drivers. However, I would need to downgrade my kernel for this. Is this a good idea, and how can I do that?
Note: I am using X11 and would rather stick to it for now as it's more time-tested.
